# get specific subdirectory in java using paths

Tags: java, directory, nio, subdirectory

to get subdirectories of a directory I am currently using

```
Paths.get(currentpath.toString(), "subdirectory");
```

is there a better method? I specifically do not like the toString call, and I'd prefer to not use `.toFile()` if possible.

I tried searching for this here but I only found answers about the old api or what I was currently using or completely unrelated questions.

Comment: Do you want all subdirs or just a specific one?

Comment: Perhaps [Path.resolve​(Path other)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve(java.nio.file.Path))?

Comment: @deHaar I want a specific one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just `resolve` the name of the subdirectory against the root `Path` like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // definition of the root directory (adjust according to your system)
    String currentPath = "C:\\";
    Path root = Paths.get(currentPath);

    // get a specific subdirectory by its name
    String specificSubDir = "temp";
    // resolve its name against the root directory
    Path specificSubDirPath = root.resolve(specificSubDir);

    // and check the result
    if (Files.isDirectory(specificSubDirPath)) {
        System.out.println("Path " + specificSubDirPath.toAbsolutePath().toString()
                + " is a directory");
    } else {
        System.err.println("Path " + specificSubDirPath.toAbsolutePath().toString()
                + " is not a directory");
    }
}
```

Since I have a directory `C:\temp\`, the output on my system is

```
Path C:\temp is a directory
```

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I wanted, I was unfamiliar with the keyword resolve in this case. I also was only looking through `Paths` and `Files`